# odd vertical alignment for mathop

Tags: spacing, macros

I have encountered an odd vertical misalignment when using `mathop` to define some one-character macros. Specifically, I am (re)defining `\i` via

```
\renewcommand{\i}{\mathop{\mathbbl{i}}}
```

(for quaternions, if you're curious), but the problems starts with

```
\renewcommand{\i}{\mathop{i}}
```

and in equations, the symbol `\i` is pushed down a bit, enough to be noticeable, and ugly (see picture below, arrow is added)! This does *not* happen with a two-character macro (or more). Dropping the `\mathop` would solve the problem, but at the expense of bad spacing after the macro. 
I am therefore looking for a fix either in the vertical spacing with `\mathop` or the horizontal spacing after the `\newcommand`.
Thanks.

[image: vertically misplaced macro]

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg ! In my search of the Stack Exchange, I had missed this post (bad choice of keywords...). This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Don't worry: I *knew* it had been dealt with; and my first and second attempt keywords weren't good. But in the second attempt I found an answer that had a reference to the right thread.